# Get the difference of two array of objects with multiple constraints

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the difference of two arrays of objects, by applying multiple AND constraints.

Find here a small example:

```js
const dbArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const diffArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company6',
    symbol: 'C6',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '5',
    stockID: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company10',
    symbol: 'C10',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const res = diffArr.filter(cv => !dbArr.find(e => e.name === cv.name)).filter(cv => !dbArr.find(e => e.ratingID === cv.ratingID)).filter(cv => !dbArr.find(e => e.stockID === cv.stockID))

console.log(res)


/* 
RESULT I would like to get:

const dbArr = [{
  name: 'Company1',
  symbol: 'C1',
  ratingID: '1',
  stockID: '2'
},
{
  name: 'Company2',
  symbol: 'C2',
  ratingID: '1',
  stockID: '2'
},
{
  name: 'Company3',
  symbol: 'C3',
  ratingID: '1',
  stockID: '2'
},
{
  name: 'Company4',
  symbol: 'C4',
  ratingID: '1',
  stockID: '2'
},
{
  name: 'Company6',
  symbol: 'C6',
  ratingID: '1',
  stockID: '2'
},
{
  name: 'Company1',
  symbol: 'C1',
  ratingID: '5',
  stockID: '3'
},
{
  name: 'Company10',
  symbol: 'C10',
  ratingID: '1',
  stockID: '2'
},
] */
```

As a final result I tried to concatenate multiple `finds`, however I get an empty array.

However, my method works if I only use `find` once.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean difference between two arrays?  Do you want an array containing all the objects that only exist in one array but not the other?

Comment: The expected result shows the symmetric difference of the two arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chain multiple `.filter`'s you're essentially saying return only the elements that meet **all** the conditions; whereas your expected array contains elements that meet **any** of the diff conditions.

```js
const dbArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const diffArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company6',
    symbol: 'C6',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '5',
    stockID: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company10',
    symbol: 'C10',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const res = diffArr.filter(cv => !dbArr.find(e => e.name === cv.name && e.ratingID === cv.ratingID && e.stockID === cv.stockID));

console.log(res)
```

Secondly, you're expected array contains not only the additional elements (elements in `diffArr` but not `dbArr`) but also the removed elements (elements in `dbArr` but not `diffArr`). To include these elements, you will have to iterate `dbArr` as well.

```js
const dbArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
];

const diffArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company6',
    symbol: 'C6',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '5',
    stockID: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company10',
    symbol: 'C10',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
];

let same = (cv1, cv2) =>
  cv1.name === cv2.name && cv1.ratingID === cv2.ratingID && cv1.stockID === cv2.stockID;

let res1 = diffArr.filter(cv1 => !dbArr.find(cv2 => same(cv1, cv2)));
let res2 = dbArr.filter(cv1 => !diffArr.find(cv2 => same(cv1, cv2)));
let res = [...res1, ...res2];

console.log(res);
```

Another note, `find` *should* be replaced with `some` as its clearer and more aligned with the intention. `array.some(predicate)` says "do any of the array's elements pass the predicate?"; whereas `find` says "which is the first element that passes the predicate?"
([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just go through both arrays and add to the result when the element is not found in the result.

```js
const dbArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const diffArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company6',
    symbol: 'C6',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '5',
    stockID: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company10',
    symbol: 'C10',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const res = [];
dbArr.map(cv => {if(res.find(e => e.name === cv.name))return cv; res.push(cv)});
diffArr.map(cv => {if(res.find(e => e.name === cv.name))return cv; res.push(cv)});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `.reduce` with `JSON.parse`, the idea is that it will check an array of strings and push the nonexistent values in the accumulator

```js
const dbArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company2',
    symbol: 'C2',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company3',
    symbol: 'C3',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company4',
    symbol: 'C4',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
]

const diffArr = [{
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company6',
    symbol: 'C6',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company1',
    symbol: 'C1',
    ratingID: '5',
    stockID: '3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Company10',
    symbol: 'C10',
    ratingID: '1',
    stockID: '2'
  },
];

const res = diffArr.reduce((acc, item, index, self) => {

  if (typeof acc !== 'object') {
    acc = [];
  }
  acc.push(JSON.stringify(item)); // push the item as a string

  dbArr.forEach(i => {
    let j = JSON.stringify(i); // make dbArr items strings
    if (acc.indexOf(j) === -1) { // check if the item exists in the accumulator
      acc.push(j); // add it
    }
  })

  if (index === self.length - 1) { // when we reach the last index, we'll convert the strings back to Objects
    acc = acc.map(i => JSON.parse(i));
  }

  return acc;

}, []);

console.log(res)
```